# Text box visible using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a hidded textbox and Imagebutton.For avoiding the Postback i am trying to make textbox visible on click of the image button using javascript.But textbox is not showing on click of the image button,Instead image btton is moving.
What could be wrong here in this code.

Appreciate ur help

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" text="From:" style=" visibility: hidden"  runat="server"  BackColor="#999999" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Double"></asp:TextBox>

 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" BackColor="#99CCFF" 
 BorderColor="#84C1FF" BorderStyle="Outset" OnClientClick="MJavascriptFunction();return false;"  Height="35px" 
ImageUrl="search11.png" Width="56px" />

<script type="text/javascript">

   function MJavascriptFunction(obj) {
       var theControl = document.getElementById("<%=Textbox2.ClientID %>");

       theControl.style.display = "block";

   }

  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
theControl.style.display = "block";
```

To

```
theControl.style.visibility="visible";
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/EUtCa/1)

In your Code you set the visiblity option to "hidden", So you need to use the same property in javscript

Alternatively you can change the HTML inline CSS to style="display:none".

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EUtCa/)**

Comment: @abcdshsu, if my answer solved your problem then it would be nice if you mark it as the answer :)